# Equivalent sql code insert/sql in entity framework in code-first

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

Equivalent  below code in entity framework in code-first

```
INSERT INTO TableA (a,b)
SELECT a,b
FROM TableB
WHERE a=10
```

Comment: What are you asking? It's not clear what your question is, especially since there are no question marks to be found anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to select few columns from `TableB` based on a condition and then adding all those objects to `TableA`, something like following can be done:

```
//Create list of TableA objects after selecting and projecting from TableB
var list = db.TableB.Where(t => t.a == 10)
                    .Select(r => new TableA() { A = r.a, B = r.b })
                    .ToList();
//Add those items to TableA through DataContext
foreach (var item in list)
    db.TableA.AddObject(item);
//Call Save
db.SaveChanges();
```